# Building "Typescript" folder to legacy javascript file architecture

Tags: javascript, typescript, migration

I'm working on a project that was originally written in plain Javascript. I've added a Typescript folder at the root level which contains the same structure as the original javascript. The filestructure looks like this:

```
|_ build
|  |_ automatically generated js files from Meta and src using build command
|
|_ meta
|  |_ foo.js, bar.js
|
|_ src
|  |_ baz.js
|
|_ typescript
|  |_ meta
|     |_ foo.ts, bar.ts
|  |_ src
|     |_ baz.ts
```

When I run tsc, I'd like all of the Typescript files within the typescript directory to compile out to the same structure they existed in in the Typescript directory to the root directory. However, most of the examples I've seen using the outDir have things building to a specific build folder.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "ES2020",
    "lib": ["ES2018"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    "outDir" : "" // what can be here to say "use include file structure - typescript dir?
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["typescript/**/*"]
}
```

I cannot wrap the Javascript directories into a "dist" folder. How should I structure my tsconfig to build to the root level, matching the same directories inside the typescript directory?

Comment: I just want to make sure I understand the directory layout you want. For example, where should `typescript/src/baz.ts` live once it has been compiled into `baz.js` ?

Comment: Are there source files in `meta` and `src`, or are those strictly output directories for the compiled typescript?

Comment: Do the source files inside `typescript` folder `import` original files from `meta` and `src` or are they completely independent? Note that they would overwrite existent js sources with equal names.

Comment: @ford04 I think there are no files in `meta` and `src`, based on the directory structure above, because the `.js` files in `meta` and `src` match the names of those under the `typescript` directory. I'm not sure, though.

Comment: @Codebling typescript/src/baz.ts should compile to src/baz.js. There are source files in src and meta.

Comment: @ford04 the source folders inside of the ts folder do import original files from src and meta.

Comment: then afaik your desired project structure is not possible unfortunately.

Comment: @ford04 Let's assume that the folders don't import from src and meta, then. I can spend time moving those imports. I'd like to see any documentation that would say that's impossible, though. In addition, I would think that if I set allowJs to false, it wouldn't try to compile those javascript files. In addition, I currently have it set up that if it would fail on trying to compile because it'd rewrite, it simply doesn't, which has worked just fine so far with the javascript imports.

Comment: @rDev have a look at the `rootDir` compiler option, which will be set to the common base folder of all inputs (proj root, if `.ts` files do import `.js` files). As consequence, there will be a subfolder `typescript` under `outDir` generated, which is not your wanted file structure. If you disable `allowJs`, TS would emit an error, in case you still have js imports. I would just go with a standard project structure with `allowJs` here.

Comment: @ford04 I've disabled allowJs and haven't had any problems with the js imports. It appears that it still is compiling my Typescript just fine (currently, the Typescript files are sitting right next to my JS files. I want to move them to the typescript folder). I don't know where you're getting the idea that there's an error, do you have a link?

I can't use a standard project structure, due to other legacy build commands I'm not able to change right now.

I've looked at rootDir and currently have it set to the project root. If there's something else I can work with, I will try that.

Comment: "currently, the Typescript files are sitting right next to my JS files" - that's the reason, why you don't get an import error - equally named `.ts` files have precedence and are taken instead of .js. So the following did work for me (if that still doesn't fit, I guess I am out  (sorry): `"outDir": ".", "rootDir": "typescript", "include": ["typescript/**/*"], "exclude": ["node_modules", "src", "meta", "build"]`. This copied all sources from `typescript` to project root and preserved the contained file structure.

Comment: @ford04 That works perfectly! Could you write that up as an answer so I can give you the bounty? Thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome, recapped some of the points down under.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap your requirements:

```
|_ meta // emit js files for typescript/meta here
|_ src  // emit js files for typescript/src here
|_ typescript // root folder for all .ts source files
|  |_ meta
|     |_ foo.ts, bar.ts
|  |_ src
|     |_ baz.ts
```

To do that, we can adjust `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "outDir": ".",
    "rootDir": "typescript"
  },
  "include": ["typescript/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "src", "meta", "build"],
}
```

Then all input `.ts` files will be emitted in the following path (relative to `tsconfig.json`):

```
emit-path: <outDir>/<filePath> minus <rootDir>  (rootDir chopped off from file path)

Example: ./typescript/src/baz.ts  -->  ./src/baz.js
```

We could leave out the [`rootDir`](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeScript-New-Handbook/reference/compiler-options/#rootdir) config option:

> **Default**: The **longest common path** of all **non-declaration input files**.
>   When TypeScript compiles files, it keeps the same directory structure in the output directory as exists in the input directory.

Though it is a good practice to make it explicit, so the compiler will trigger an error, if something is wrong with the location of the input files.

Comment: I get an error whenever the output directory contains the source files

Comment: `$ tsc --version`: `Version 3.8.3`. `error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file`

Comment: That is why you also specify the additional `"exclude"` entries.  Above will exclude `src` and `meta`, which are the emit folders for OP.

Comment: Yes I just tried with the `exclude` and it works. Nice job. (I still think compiling to another source folder is a really bad approach, however)

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you and also suggested a more standard approach. Apparently @rDev has specific requirements

Comment: @ford04 Something I noticed today is that it seems like relative references won't work if any of the Typescript files relatively import a file from either src or meta. Just as a word of caution for anyone else reading this question.

Comment: @rDev that's why I asked you before, if the .ts files import something from `src` and  `meta` (:   These folders are excluded from sources with above config and we made them to "emit folders", so this cannot work. Also you would get an error for `rootDir` now, as it does not contain all sources anymore. Changing this setting would lead to additional nested folders (e.g. `typescript`)

Comment: Ah gotcha. I noticed that tsc doesn't throw an error if I remove `meta` and `src` from the exclusions, so I wasn't sure if it was handling the way you anticipated. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score -1):

#### Summary

<strike>The answer is no. (At least not with a single build step/config)</strike>

This is possible, see [ford04's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60623754/675721).

#### Why this is a bad idea

1. Your output artifacts are now mingled with other source/input artifacts. Why is this bad? 
   Consider what would happen if you deleted a folder under `typescript/src`, for example `typescript/src/some-utils`. Because it has already compiled, this folder and all of the compiled source files under it already exists in the `src/some-utils` directory. Next compilation, they will still be there. How can we clean this? Normally, a "clean" step exists before build, and it will simply delete the output directoy and recompile. But now there are source files in the `src`!

   We have no easy way of distinguishing source files and typescript output files. We could delete the `src` directory and then `git checkout -- src` to restore the source files. But what if we were in the middle of editing some files? I suppose we could stash our changes: `git stash; rm -rf src; git checkout -- src; git stash pop;`. But untracked files are still lost! Ok.. `git add src; git stash; rm -rf src; git checkout -- src; git stash pop; git restore --staged src`. This fixes things, mostly, but any staged files we have are still unstaged. You can see how complicated this has become.

   But there is an additional and more serious problem with this layout. We can't `.gitignore` any Typescript file, so Git will constantly show untracked files. There is no way to detect if someone accidentally commits a compiled Typescript file. The problem may become compounded if someone attempts to make changes to a committed compiled Typescript file. These changes will be overwritten by the Typescript compiler on each run, and the changes will be lost.
2. You have source roots at two levels with the folder hierarchy. Conceptually, these should be at the same level, and all of your source files should be in one folder.

#### A better approach

When migrating Javascript to Typescript, a good approach is to start by adding Typescript annotations to the Javascript files. This way, you keep all of the advantages of Typescript without adding any complexity to your process. When a Javascript file is nearly fully annotated, convert it into a Typescript `.ts` file (this enforces the use of Typescript for any changes to this file in the future), **but leave it alongside the Javascript files**. Then, when compiling, simply set `allowJs` to `true` and the Typescript compiler will happily output all of your Javascript files to the Typescript output directory.

You mentioned that you cannot wrap your Javascript files into a `dist` or any output/build folder, but it's not clear why. This seems like the major blocker in moving forward with this.

Comment: Thank you for the input, I really appreciate hearing this perspective.

Comment: This project is being used as a POC on a legacy repo. The company may decide to not use TS. As a result, it is necessary to implement this without changing any other part of the build process, which includes the file structure. This is why the TS files we are testing out to replace the current works are kept separately. One of the biggest points is that we don't want to distinguish between the legacy src and the new output, to show how typescript won't uproot our previous styles. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: @rDev, that's what I figured. I worry that such a proof-of-concept would actually cause people to reject it due to the points I highlighted (I personally would reject such a setup). I outlined the other approaches which may work better. I'm glad if this perspective is helpful to you (although in that case I'm not sure why the downvote). Best of luck either way !